# Alternative Rails to Validation Framework

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a semi-complex application i'm building that has various wizards and screens.  I would like to do server-side validation but not use the built in validation in rails.  Basically, I need to do different types of validation on the same type of object, in different contexts.  In one case, i may validate 3 out of 5 of the object's attributes.  In another only one, in a third all of them.  I don't really want to have a bunch of :if => {} lambdas in my models' validations either. That gets ugly as the number of contexts grows.

Is there some alternative validation framework for rails that can do this?

Comment: anyone else have a suggestion?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same need.  You might have a look at Verity and Semantic-Attributes.  Both have their own DSL for defining validations.  Semantic Attributes depends on rails, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Consider extracting the complex validation rules into their own class and then `extend` that into the base model class.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying i can put the validations in a module and then add them to the model using extend at runtime?

Comment: i tried this, but the validation methods in rails must go into a class or they fail.  Yet extend, requires a module.